# Hibernate save or update with JoinColumn

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I would have a problem with create a new entity, if it have a join column.

Entity:

@

```
Entity
@Table(name = "projects")
public class Project {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy = "increment")
    @Column(name = "id_project")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "project_name")
    private String name;

    @JsonInclude(value = Include.NON_NULL)
    @Column(name = "project_language")  
    private String language;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    @Column(name = "start_date")
    private Date start_date;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    @Column(name = "end_date")
    private Date end_date;

    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_content_manager")
    private User contentManager;
```

if i send this json:

```
{
    "name": "prova3",
    "language": "1",
    "start_date": "15-04-2018",
    "end_date": "26-04-2018"

}
```

the result are:

```
Hibernate: insert into projects (id_content_manager, end_date, project_language, project_name, start_date, id_project) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
WARN : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 1452, SQLState: 23000
ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dipp`.`projects`, CONSTRAINT `projects_user_id_user_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`id_project`) REFERENCES `user` (`id_user`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ERROR: org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl - HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement]
```

the method for save the entity:

```
public void newProject(Project project) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        Transaction tx = null;

        tx = session.beginTransaction();

        if(session != null) {
            try {
                session.save(project);
                tx.commit();
                session.close();
            }catch(Exception ex) {
                session.close(); 
            }
        }
    }
```

Someone could help me to solve?
I would need to understand how to pass the parameter "contentManager" as optional in order to pass only the id and then through a find function to retrieve everything and pass it to contentManager

Edit:

The controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json" , produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<BaseModel> newProject( @RequestHeader(value="Authorization") String token, @RequestBody Project project, Locale locale) throws ParseException{
        if(!SecurityUtil.validateToken(token)) {
            return new ResponseEntity<BaseModel>(new BaseModel("error", MessageHandler.returnMessage("invalid_token", locale)), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
        User contentManager = new User();
        logger.info(project.getContentManager().getId().toString());
        if(project.getContentManager().getId() != null) {
            logger.info("have id");
            contentManager = userDao.find(project.getContentManager().getId());
        }
        project.setContentManager(contentManager);
        projectDao.newProject(project);
        return new ResponseEntity<BaseModel>(new BaseModel("ok", project.getId()), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Comment: As per my experience if you a relation, we  need to insert the relation first and then associate with the parent.

Comment: @LearningPhase afaik that's what cascade setting in the relationship for.  However it depends on how OP is dealing with the User though...

Comment: Remove the 'cascade = CascadeType.ALL' from 'ManyToOne' relation. Cascade be more useful in 'User' entity. You probably try to save project with empty user.

Comment: @AdamLesiak the result is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the foreign key `projects_user_id_user_fk` remove "ON UPDATE CASCADE" and set "ON UPDATE NO ACTION", because when you insert the id it try to update user table and you probably try to save project with empty user.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, besides your suggestion, I realized that I had mistaken the foreing key danto "id_project" and "id_user" instead of "id_content_manager" and "id_user"

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer. Below is the way I have done, this might help you. Before using it I initialize it and set then set it to use in the parent entity.

```
Icon icon = new Icon();
icon.setIconPath(MiscUtils.getUserIconPath(user));
icon.setUser(user);
user.setIcon(icon);
```

Comment: nope, i edit the post, but with this method not work